# How to set font when using greek characters?

Tags: fonts, xetex, greek

I have tried this with the font "Charis SIL", "Times" and "Times New Roman":

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,british]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}

This is a simple test. \textgreek{ὅθεν ὤφειλεν κατὰ πάντα}. And orgé as well.

Without slash textgreek ἱλαστήριον (hilasterion)

\end{document}
```

The é appears in the PDF when using `xelatex`, but the greek does not, no matter which font I use, and the `Charis SIL` font should have these characters, they work in other programs with this font. This is what I get in the logs, perhaps I am not setting the front properly? Any tips would be much appreciated.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/CharisSIL(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 15.

Missing character: There is no ὅ in font grmn1000!
Missing character: There is no θ in font grmn1000!
Missing character: There is no ε in font grmn1000!
....
Missing character: There is no ἱ in font Charis SIL/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no τ in font Charis SIL/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;!
```

[image]

Comment: Don't load `fontenc`.

Comment: Commenting out `fontenc`, but sadly it doesn't help.

Comment: Doesn't help how? It will avoid the problem you posted warnings from.

Comment: Im not so much worried about the warnings‚Mainly I just care about the letters appearing in the PDF.

Comment: Yes, but the warnings tell you why nothing appears. However, I'm afraid I'd forgotten that `greek` Babel does this. You need to drop Babel and use Polyglossia instead. Or redefine all the stuff in `greek.ldf` that use `LGR` encoding, which you don't want. But that would be a PITA so just use Polyglossia.

Comment: @cfr I didn't know the difference between bible and polyglossa, but this appears to be the key. Thanks

Comment: It is specific to Greek, as far as I know. Babel generally works fine with `fontspec` etc. and Polyglossia is an alternative. But Babel's Greek support won't work with the modern engines and `fontspec` because the language files enforce a non-unicode encoding.

Comment: @cfr Interesting! Thanks for the info. Non-unicode encoding! Latex really does need an update. I both really love it, and I really hate it. :D

Comment: I should have said: it enforces a non-unicode output encoding. You can still use a unicode input encoding. But `fontspec` wants unicode for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this, although this is not quite right. At least, it doesn't quite work for me because Charis SIL does not support Greek. At least, the version I have does not:

```
otfinfo -s /usr/share/fonts/ttf-charis-sil-ibx/CharisSIL-R.ttf 
DFLT            Default
cyrl            Cyrillic
cyrl.SRB        Cyrillic/Serbian
latn            Latin
latn.IPPH       Latin/Phonetic transcription—IPA conventions
latn.VIT        Latin/Vietnamese
```

However, if you substitute a suitable font, it should work fine.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}

This is a simple test. \textgreek{ὅθεν ὤφειλεν κατὰ πάντα}. And orgé as well.

Without slash textgreek ἱλαστήριον (hilasterion)

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been working on this for hours trying to get it to work, this is perfect. — Regarding `Charis SIL`, this is confusing, this font is explicitly designed for printing these characters, and works in other apps. I wonder why it doesn't work in latex.

Comment: @Jacob Well it says that it does not support Greek. The fact that it has the characters is irrelevant. It doesn't support Greek script.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking [Charis SIL](http://software.sil.org/charis/) was designed for Latin and Cyrillic scripts. See the FAQ: [Why does the font have some Greek characters, but not all?](http://software.sil.org/charis/support/faq/):

> While it is true that the font includes some Greek characters, it is
>   not intended to provide general support for the Greek language. Those
>   Greek characters that were included were done so in order to support
>   various (primarily linguistic) notational systems. If Greek language
>   support is needed, the [Galatia SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=GalatiaSIL) and [Gentium](http://software.sil.org/gentium/) fonts are two available options.

---

For what it's worth, I also like [GFS Artemisia](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsartemisia/):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
% \newfontfamily\greekfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{GFS Artemisia}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}

\begin{document}

This is a simple test. \textgreek{ὅθεν ὤφειλεν κατὰ πάντα}. And orgé as well.

% note: the Greek will fail here because you are not using \greekfont (and Charis SIL doesn't have the characters)
Without slash textgreek ἱλαστήριον (hilasterion)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, my memory from the time I download this font, is obviously somewhat faulty. Thanks.

Comment: @Jacob -- Cheers. I had the same belief, too, though I can't remember where it came from now....

Comment: This will get you American English rather than British, as in the original MWE, I believe.

Comment: @cfr -- yes, very true. Fixed. It was not my intention to privilege, tacitly American hyphenation..!

Comment: @jon ;) Can't upvote again, mind :(.